# Tables automatically deleted with no action to cause this

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a few java lambda functions that depend on dynamoDB. The issue I am having is that my tables are being automatically deleted from AWS for no reason. Has anyone had this happen to them ?

Comment: They're not being automatically deleted. I would suspect that you're looking in the wrong region or wrong account, or that a person, or process, with appropriate IAM credentials for your account is deleting them. CloudTrail Logs can help you determine which credentials are doing what. You could also modify suspect IAM policies to deny dynamodb:DeleteTable temporarily while you investigate.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have one function capable of deleting the tables. In the process of locking it down now with the appropriate security group.

Comment: Security Groups are firewalls for compute, which are unrelated. You need to deal with IAM policies, which authorize actions against resources.

Answer (score 1):

Enable CloudTrail logs and you will be able to see who deleted the tables next time this happens. There is a tutorial on how to do this [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-create-a-trail-using-the-console-first-time.html).

Btw, double check that you're in the right region because sometimes I find all my AWS resources missing and then I notice I'm in the wrong region.

Comment: Ok looking into these things. Thanks for the advice.